# Bash - How to increase positive numbers by constant and decrease negative ones by same constant? (Awk/sed probably)

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a multiple files of numbers like:

file1.txt

```
 0.77031
-10.25150   2.80417   3.62904  -9.72425   1.41742   7.96870
-24.75966
-11.22983   21.17503  -0.74532
-13.55239
```

I need to change every positive number by +x and every negative one by -x. Lets have x=8

I tried awk script for this:

```
for a in $@; do
awk '{FS=OFS="." }/-/{$1-=16}1' $a | awk '{FS=OFS="." }/\d*/{$1+=8}1'
done
```

but it seems to work only on first number in line. How to make it work for all numbers in line?

**Wanted output:**

```
 8.77031
-18.25150   10.80417   11.62904  -17.72425   9.41742   15.96870
-32.75966
-19.22983   29.17503  -8.74532
-21.55239
```

I thought about using sed, but it seems to not work well for increasing and deceasing numbers

Comment: I tried to find the float numbers by finding the `.`. Becouse i didn't know how to find positive numbers thus I decreased 16 from negative ones and afterwards I added 8 for every one. Loop is becouse the files are more than one.

Comment: As an aside, `for a in $@` is basically always wrong. You probably want `for a in "$@"` or (distant second) `for a in $*`. Probably try http://shellcheck.net/ before asking for human assistance.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that! Thanks!

Comment: All you need is `awk 'script' "$@"` instead of `for i in "$@"; do awk 'script' "$i"; done`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -v n=8 '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) $i += ($i<0 ? -n : n)} 1' file
8.77031
-18.2515 10.8042 11.629 -17.7242 9.41742 15.9687
-32.7597
-19.2298 29.175 -8.74532
-21.5524
```

Comment: Perhaps also note that Awk accepts an arbitrary number of input files, so the `for` loop in the question can be replaced with `awk '...' "$@"`

Comment: I am not sure, if I am doing something wrong, but this will change float numbers to intergers for me.
`$ awk -v n=8 '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) $i += ($i<0 ? -n : n)} 1' file.txt`
Output:

`8
-18 10 11 -17 9 15
-32
-19 29 -8
-21
`
The pattern is allright

Comment: I can't repro that. Demo: https://ideone.com/Txf7iC Do you have some formatting variable set in the environment?

Comment: I don't think so, but I will check it.

Comment: It may have something to do with locales. Setting `LC_ALL=C` works for me.

Comment: You're in a locale where the decimal separator is something other than `.` (probably `,`) so when you do numeric operations awk truncates `1.2` to `1` just like it'd truncate `1x2` which is why setting the locale to `C` lets this work so the `.` is considered part of the number.